# How to upload data to Jupyter Notebook from blob storage in Azure?

Tags: azure, hadoop, apache-spark, ipython

I created cluster on HDInsight (Azure), created Ipython Notebook and uploaded text file to blob storage. How can I upload it to notebook? Hope there is some url of this file in blob storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jupyter notebooks are a web-based UI to run queries against HDInsight (and other data sources).  They do not have a mechanism to upload data into blob storage; they are only able to tell Apache Spark (for example) to query data within blob storage.

To work with data within HDInsight Azure, you will need to upload the files into HDFS or into blob storage (the latter is the more common mechanism).  To upload data into blob storage, here are some good references:

- [Upload data for Hadoop jobs in HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-upload-data)
- [Use HDFS-compatible Azure Blob storage with Hadoop in HDInsight](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage)